# Redirecting new users onboarding page using Supabase Auth UI component

Tags: next.js, supabase

New Supabase user here!

When a new user signs up, I want to redirect that user to an onboarding survey page. When an existing user signs in, they should be redirected to the home page (denoted by "/" in my current code). I'm using [Supabase's pre-built Auth UI component](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/auth-ui).

How can this be accomplished? My code for login page below:

```
import { useSupabaseClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";
import { Auth } from "@supabase/auth-ui-react";
import { ThemeSupa } from "@supabase/auth-ui-shared";

export default function LoginPage() {
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient();

  return (
    <div className="items-center justify-center mx-12 h-screen">
      <Auth
        redirectTo= "/"
        supabaseClient={supabase}
        appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa }}
        theme="dark"
        providers={["google"]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Supabase auth does not give you a special event for newly signed up users. I'd recommend you track this in your public.users table with a `onboarding_survey_timestamp` column that is null at the start and you update it with the timestamp when they filled the survey, or something like that.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm going to implement your suggestion. Thank you.